# How to use addStaticLabels with mapview

Tags: r, maps, mapview

I am trying to use `addStaticLabels` with mapview but the outline of the map disapears. Could someone help me figure out what's going on?

If I run:

```
library(mapview)
library(leafem)
 mapview(franconia)
```

It works as expected.

But running it like so:

```
mapview(franconia) %>% addStaticLabels(., label = franconia$NAME_ASCI)
```

It prints the labels but the outline of franconia goes away. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the map directly into the label function:

```r
library(mapview)
library(leafem)


mapview(franconia) |> 
  addStaticLabels(label = franconia$NAME_ASCI)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Still doesn't work on mine. `I have mapview 2.11.2 and leafem 0.2.3 running on R-4.1.1`

Comment: I'm running with R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt) with the same version of the two packages. Possibly updating to a more recent version of R may be a solution, assuming the output in the answer is what you are looking for?

Comment: I will update my R version. Thanks @Peter